# Jenkins assign variable in ssh command

Tags: variables, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, remote-server

[image]

I declared the variable logfile in the environment part and was trying to assign its value after executing `ls -t -c1 *.log | head -1` command in the remote system.

I know i am doing it the wrong way.Any ideas how to assign the variable value after executing command in the remote system?

Comment: @T M Suhas Does the solution I provided works for you

Comment: No it’s showing errors

Comment: It’s indeed working but need to write it inside script{}, but how to use the variable inside the sshget command ??

Comment: @T M Suhas you can access using ``${logResult}``. I added example in answer

Comment: Yeah when I use echo ${logResult} it’s printing but when I pass the variable to sshGet as shown in figure it’s not resolving the value

Comment: Try passing in ``"`` instead of ``'``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233036/discussion-between-altaf-and-t-m-suhas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take return value in a variable in below way :

```
# Declare variable init
def logResult
logResult = sshCommand remote: remote, command: "ls -t -c1 *.log | head -1"
```

You can use it in script as:

```
script {
 test = sh(script "echo ${logResult}")
 }
```